# applescript change timestamp of files recursevly (for sorting an FAT32-stick by name)

Tags: sorting, applescript, fat32

since there is no tool on mac to sort a USB-stick (FAT32) by name to play music files in a car that cannot sort the files by itself, i want to create a little applescript to do this.
There are tools like "drivesort" on Windows that can do this but since wine is not working on Catalina this is no option for me. On mac there are many tools to clean from hidden files on drives, but i haven't found any to sort a FAT by name...

my idea was to get the file list, sort it by name (if it is not) and then use the touch command to change to date of the file.
as i know FAT32 stores the files not sorted but only by the time the files were added on the stick.

here is my appescript, but it errors that on the line where "a" will be set, it cannot convert into the expected type:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set file_list to every file of entire contents of (choose folder with prompt "Please select directory.")
end tell

repeat with afile in file_list
    set a to quoted form of POSIX path of afile
    display dialog "aktuelle Datei: " & a as string
    do shell script "touch -am " & a
end repeat
```

what i am doing wrong here?
is there a better simplier way?
many thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, but wanted to mention that you should check the granularity of the time on FAT filesystems - I seem to recall it may not be any better than 2 seconds, and you may `touch` hundreds of files in that time...

Comment: that is a good point... maybe it is better to use a tool or a bash script to copy the sorted list on the empty stick (since i have those files in a folder on my mac). Is there a way to force to copy a folder in a sorted way onto the stick. Then the files should be sorted on the stick without manuallly sorting them directly on the stick?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do really. The sorting of a bunch of files isn't really in the filesystem itself, it is in the tool or program that reads it. You could set the time for the first file to be 0 (presumably 1 Jan 1970) and the second one to be 5 seconds later and the third one to be 10 seconds later and so on... maybe... if that's what you are interested in doing.

Comment: yes, that was my plan, but i don't know if that would work. Meanwhile i found this: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/fatsort.1.html and download url is: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/fatsort but how can i use this on a mac?

Comment: it work, but (maybe because of catalina restriction) it says that i have not permissions to make changes to the stick... but i can write to it etc.

Comment: Look in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > * and make sure **Script Editor** has the proper permissions.

Comment: i put fatsort, my Droplet and the Scripteditor the permissions the full rights for drives in those preferences, no change. The error is: main: WARNING: The C locale does not support all multibyte characters!
openFileSystem: Operation not permitted!
sortFileSystem: Failed to open file system!
main: Failed to sort file system!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Finder* should be able to sort the files and also adjust the modification dates of each.  So something like this <strike>(which I admit I haven't yet tested but will do so when I am in front of a computer)</strike>:

```
set now to the current date

tell application id "com.apple.Finder" to repeat with f in (sort ¬
    the files in my (choose folder)'s entire contents by name)
    set [f's modification date, f's creation date, now] to ¬
        [now, now, now + 5]
end repeat
```

Comment: if have tried this on a testfolder on my desktop and on my USB-stick - in both cases the modification date did not change. i tried to insert a output within the loop to check if the loop will be called, but nothing gets displayed: set now to the current date

tell application id "com.apple.Finder" to repeat with f in ¬
 (sort files in (choose folder) by name) as alias list
 display dialog f
 set [f's modification date, now] to [now, now + 5]
end repeat

Comment: sorry, my fault! it works, but only if files are within the folder an not in the subfolders - my bad. i forgot to tell you that i need this recursively - how do i achieve that? many thanks!

Comment: Sorry, have just seen these comments.  I've updated the answer to include `entire contents`, so it should now work recursively.  It also updates the `creation date`, but that might not be necessary so can be taken out (though it does no harm if it remains). Thanks for the green tick!

Answer (score 0):

sorts the selected folder by setting the modification date

```
set now to the current date
set MyFolder to choose folder with prompt "Folder to be sorted"

tell application "Finder"
    set SubFolders to every folder of entire contents of MyFolder

    -- sort files in the root of the selected folder
    tell application id "com.apple.Finder"
        repeat with f in ¬
            (sort files in MyFolder by name) as alias list
            set [f's modification date, now] to [now, now + 60]
        end repeat
    end tell

    -- loop through every subfolders
    repeat with aSubFolder in SubFolders
        tell application id "com.apple.Finder"
            set [aSubFolder's modification date, now] to [now, now + 60]
        end tell
        tell application id "com.apple.Finder"
            repeat with f in ¬
                (sort files in aSubFolder by name) as alias list
                set [f's modification date, now] to [now, now + 60]
            end repeat
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: too bad that the FAT stores the files in the order the files and folders were stored to the stick, so changing mod or creation date do not change anything on the order the are played on those music players :(

Comment: You don't need about 3/4 of this script.  If you look at mine, that will adjust modification/creation dates of every file contained within the chosen folder and any of its subfolders.  If you need it to adjust modification dates of folders as well as files, change the word `files` in my script to `items`.